# Effects of Planetary Neutron Bombardment

Tags: planets, aliens, nuclear

A space civilization blackmails Earth by bombarding Venus with massive amounts of neutrons.

It's one of their main technologies and there are reasons for not doing it otherwise.

What would be the effect of bombarding a planet with a lot of high-energy neutrons?  Would...

- Venus get even hotter?
- Venus become highly radioactive?
- Venus be disintegrated?
- Venus will be terraformed?
- Any of above depending on the amount, concentration or duration of the bombarding?

To answer you can consider the option below that seens more plausible for you as the source of the neutrons:

- Maybe they are disintegrating Mercury (to use its neutrons)
- Maybe they are converting huge amounts of energy absorbed from the Sun into newly created neutrons.
- Maybe there's a better source and I'll ask it in another question.

Comment: Could you focus this question more? Right now it seems a question where it doesn't matter really what the answer is, except that there are neutrinos involved with Venus.

Comment: This reads like asking us to generate ideas for you. Or not even that because there's not a single question mark.

Comment: How fast are those neutrons moving? How many neutrons specifically? Both pieces of data are of the essence when asking what the effect would be.

Comment: Why are they disintegrating Mercury?

Answer (score 4):

## It's really just the heat energy

The half life of free neutrons is only around 10 minutes, so except for some weird things happening right around the beam for a short time, they're really just dumping a lot of very hot hydrogen (as the neutron decays into a proton and electron) into Venus's atmosphere. So yes, Venus would become hotter if there is enough energy in the beam to do that. If there is even more energy, it could be enough that the planet exceeds the gravitational binding energy of the Venusian system and therefore disintegrate the planet, as a lot of things would be moving fast enough, due to the heat. to escape the planet's gravity.

Note there is practically no difference here between a neutron beam and any other kind of method of adding heat energy to something.

Answer (score -1):

The effects of bombarding Venus with high-energy neutrons (10 MeV to 1000 MeV) might be:

- **Surface Temperature:** Some neutrons would penetrate the dense atmosphere, possibly heating the surface
- **Radioactivity:** Interactions between neutrons and atmospheric molecules could generate radioactive isotopes, increasing Venus's radioactivity, especially in the upper atmosphere.
- **Plate Tectonics and Geological Structure:** Given Venus's lack of active plate tectonics, significant changes are unlikely. However, intense bombardment might heat the subsurface layers, potentially influencing the behavior of magma beneath the surface and possibly increasing volcanic activity, especially if the energy input is sustained over a long period.